# $E = \mathbb{R}\times e$ is a n-dimensional measure zero if $e \subset \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ of (n-1) dimensional measure zero

Tags: real-analysis

In the book of *Mathematical Analysis II* by Zurich, at page 116 it is asked that

> Show that if a set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$  is the direct product of
>    $\mathbb{R}\times e$ of the line $\mathbb{R}$, and a set $e \subset
>  \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ of (n-1) dimensional measure zero, then $E$ is a set
>   of n-dimensional measure zero.

But, I cannot see how can this be, and do not know how to prove it, so I would appreciate any help for proving this statement.

**Edit:**

I do not understand the given answer, so please feel free to post another answers.

Comment: What point of it you didn't understand?

Comment: @Netchaiev Almost every point that the answer provides because as I have said in the comment, I do not know what those notations are and haven't studied Borel sets and etc.

Comment: The borel set doesn't change the proof : you need them because not every set is mesurable, but you can "forget" that if you don't know them. You just have to use (even if it is not true for every set) "if $A\subset \mathbb{R}^k$ and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$" and use the rest word to word...  For the notation $E_m \uparrow E$ I already explained it to you... What are the other issues?

Comment: @Netchaiev So instead you can say $A$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n $ ?

Comment: Yes, no problem to that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the construction of the product measure $\lambda_n$ (Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb{R}^n$),

> if $A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^k)$ and $B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n-k})$, ($0<k<n$), then 
>   $$ \lambda_n(A\times B) =\lambda_k(A)\lambda_{n-k}(B)$$

So here (using also that if $E_m \uparrow E$, $\lim_{m\rightarrow +\infty}\lambda_n(E_m)=\lambda_n(E)$)
$$\begin{align*}
 \lambda_n(E)&= \lambda_n(\mathbb{R}\times e) \\
&=\lim_{m\rightarrow +\infty}\lambda_n((-m,m)\times  e)\\
&=\lim_{m\rightarrow +\infty}\lambda_1((-m,m))\times \lambda_{n-1}(e)\\
 &=\lim_{m\rightarrow +\infty}\lambda_1((-m,m))  \times 0 \\
&= 0
\end{align*}
 $$

Comment: I'm having hard time to understand your notation. What does $B(\mathbb{R}^2) $ stands for ? or the symbol of "up" ? Can you write your proof more explicitly, please ?

Comment: $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^p)$ is the Borel set of $\mathbb{R}^p$, or, if you prefer the set of subsets who can be measured (not every subset is measurable!) ; the notation $E_m \uparrow E$ is equivalent to $E_1\subset E_2 \subset \cdots \subset E_m \subset \cdots$ and $\bigcup_{m\geq 1}E_m =E$.

Comment: In the book, borel sets are not mentioned.

Comment: As far as I understood, $\lambda_n$ denotes the $n-$dimensional measure, (or mesh ?) is it true ?

Comment: Yes, you understand it well $\lambda_n$ is the $n$-dimensional measure.

Comment: What are those reversed closed parenthesis mean ?

Comment: Plus, how can you be sure that $\lambda_1 ([-m, m])$ is finite ? After all, $m\to \infty$, and, if you can't, then the product wouldn't have to have zero measure.

Comment: $]-m,m[$ is a notation for $(-m,m)$ ; I can change that -> cf my edit

Comment: I see why you preferred that notation, now.

Comment: By definition of the (Lebesgue) measure on $\mathbb{R}$ (it is implied when we are talking of sets being measurable on $\mathbb{R}^n$, that theyare with respect to the Lebsgue measure), that $\lambda_1([-m,m])=\lambda_1((-m,m))= m-(-m)=2m<\infty$.

Comment: $2m < \infty $ even if $ m \to \infty$ ? I couldn't understand.

Comment: I mean $2m < \infty$ implies $m$ is finite, but this is not the case because we are sending $m$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Yes, 2m is finite since $m\in \mathbb{R}$! You are looking the limit $\lim_{m\rightarrow}u_m$ with the sequel which each term are define by $u_m := \lambda_1((-m,m))\times \lambda_{n-1}(e)$ ; then, to compute the limit you have to compute BEFORE each term of the sequence, and here each term are $u_m=  \lambda_1((-m,m))\times \lambda_{n-1}(e)=2m*0=0$. The limit of a sequence $(u_m)_{m\geq 1}$ with each term being null is $0$... right?

Comment: Then how is it valid to say $\lambda (\mathbb{R}\times e ) = \lambda ( [lim_{m\to \infty} (-m, m)]\times e) = \lim_{m \to \infty} \lambda_1 ((-m,m)) \times \lambda_1 (e )$ ? i.e how can you interchange the order of limit with measure ?

Comment: Because of the property I recalled : $\lim_{m\rightarrow +\infty}\lambda_n(E_m)=\lambda_n(\lim_{m\rightarrow +\infty} E_m)$ (using the same abuse of notation you did :  "$\lim_{m\rightarrow +\infty} E_m$" being $\bigcup_{m\geq 1}E_m:=E$, with $E_1\subset E_2 \subset \cdots $). It is true that without this theorem, it would not been valid.